# Why i cant see my buttons?

Tags: java, background, jbutton

why if i have an image background i cant see all my buttons? only if my arrow go on button i see it..

this is my jlabel with background:

```
   JLabel sfondo = new JLabel("");
    sfondo.setBounds(0, 0, 832, 527);
    contentPane.add(sfondo);
    sfondo.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
            "C:\\Users\\bocci\\workspace\\it's time of the      series\\src\\immagini\\icone\\sfondo.jpg"));
    sfondo.setIcon(icona3.newicona(patchsfondo, sfondo));
```

and i have 5 jbuttons

```
    JButton btnOpzioni = new JButton("Opzioni");
    btnOpzioni.setBounds(497, 5, 67, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnOpzioni);
```

i see only first button.

Comment: Let's see your layout, please.

Comment: Feel free to delete question

Comment: please edit your question and add some more code.. @AndyWiesendanger

Comment: If you resolved your problem, you may answer your own question with an answer below.